# Application of the Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

Consider $X_i\sim Exp(\lambda=1)$, i.e. $f_X(x)=e^{-x}$. Is it true that for a large $N$ the CLT can be used for the average $\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}ln(X_i)$ can be approached by the normal distribution? I am aware that it is sufficient to prove that $V[ln(X_i)]<\infty$ and $E[ln(X_i)]<\infty$, but does that apply in this case?

My first result was that $E[ln(X_i)]=\infty$, but I am doubting that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pdf of $X$ is given by:
$$ f_X(x) = e^{-x}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{x>0}$$
then $Y=\log(X)$ is supported on $\mathbb{R}$ and:
$$\mathbb{P}[Y<c]=\mathbb{P}[X<e^c]=1-e^{-e^c}$$
so:
$$ f_Y(x) = \exp(x-e^x)$$
and:
$$ \mathbb{E}[Y]=-\gamma,\qquad \mathbb{E}[Y^2]=\gamma^2+\zeta(2), $$
hence $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\log(X_i)$ is approximated by a normal variable with mean $-\gamma$ and variance $\zeta(2)$.

Here $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) and $\zeta(2)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$